# Counting distinct entries in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am a beginning in MySQL and am using a sample database with an offices table listing all the offices in various states.  I want to count up the number of states that offices are in, eliminating the one state with two offices.

I know that

```
SELECT DISTINCT state
FROM offices
WHERE state NOT IN('NULL');
```

will return to me all the distinct states (4 total) but I want to count them up.  I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS unique_states
FROM offices 
WHERE state IN(
SELECT DISTINCT state
FROM offices
WHERE state NOT IN('NULL'));
```

but this still returns 5, even though there should be only 4.

Any help?

Comment: What is 'NULL'? Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a nested query to achieve that.
Also, I think you mean to use `state IS NOT NULL` instead of `state NOT IN('NULL')`.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT state) 
FROM offices 
WHERE state IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a sub/nested query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT state
  FROM offices
  WHERE state NOT IN('NULL')) AS `distinct_states`
```